# For which materials is the Bethe lattice a good model to compute the density of states of the conduction band?

Tags: electronic-structure, model-hamiltonians, electron-correlation

The [Bethe lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bethe_lattice) is exactly solvable in the limit where each lattice site has an infinite number of nearest-neighbors. In this limit it yields a semi-circular density of states in the conduction band. In which specific materials is it a good model for the electronic structure?

Comment: Could you provide a bit more detail about the Bethe lattice or a link to a diagram, etc. Bethe was a genius, so there are a lot of things with similar names, haha

Comment: [This paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0409730) references some applications to amorphous materials. Maybe those references, or citations to that paper, could be a useful starting point.

Comment: @pdd86 was Anyon's suggestion helpful at all?